# Good coming from bad

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Someone said a word, or saying, to me that I didn't know the meaning, so I looked it up.

I cannot remember what it was, but the meaning was:

> "Something good comes from something that was bad"

For example, I crashed my car into a beautiful woman's car and we then dated.

Please can someone tell me the word I'm looking for. I think it is two words, each with two syllable's.

Thanks for any help anyone can give.

Comment: 'a blessing in disguise'   ?

Comment: Not what I'm looking for but thanks Tom22.

Comment: I've seen "Beauty after Tragedy", but don't think "Beautiful Tragedy" works quite the same way.

Comment: . Lucky bastard?

Comment: Every cloud has a silver lining?

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but try *eucatastrophe*.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you're referring to—

> *Every cloud has a silver lining.*

Granted, it's not two words with two syllables each, but maybe something good will come out of it even if it's a bad suggestion.

---

From [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Every+cloud+has+a+silver+lining)

*Proverb*—You can derive some benefit from every bad thing that happens to you; there is something good even in an unpleasant situation.

Answer (score 4):

[Silver lining](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/silver%20lining) describes a choice, hidden treasure that looms inside a cloud of bad weather.

> something good that can be found in a bad situation (MW)

Usually, the cloud outweighs the silver, but, hey, be thankful for small favors. Dating your victim would be a silver lining to the cloud of the crash.

Also, a diamond in the rough means the item is already a jewel, but needs some crafting to sparkle.

Comment: Hi Yosef. :) I edited your answer to include a source (this is the expectation here, so that the reader can confirm if desired). I believe this answer is correct, but will lose votes without the back-up. Feel free to roll back if this is not to your liking.